# How to pass key to react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks, jsx

I know this is a very basic question and even beginners can do this. But somehow I am getting this error:

> index.js:1 Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key"
> prop.
>
> Check the render method of `FilterProducts`.

Here is my code

```
const filterList = filterBy.map((f, i) => {
    const key = Object.keys(f);
    return (
      <div key={i} className="filter">
        <h4 className="filter__header">{key}</h4>
        {f[key].map((val) => {
          return (
            <CheckBoxInput
              changeVal={(e) => changeValHandler(e, key)}
              value={val.toLowerCase()}
              label={val}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  });
```

I am rendering 2 lists, I provided the key to the first list and as for the second one I don't know how to pass a key. It's a component and if I pass key to that component, it complains that key can't be passed as a prop.
Give me some help here please

Comment: A key should be something unique that identifiers each mapped element. In the absence of that you can always use the current array index, just like you do with `<div key={i} ...`. What's stopping you from applying that exact same solution?

Comment: The CheckBoxInput should have a `key="..."`. You could probably use `val` as your key unless two inputs will have the same val

Comment: It's weird. I did it prior to asking question here. Back then I got warning saying that I cant use key as a prop because it will be undefined. But actually I didn't want to pass key as prop. Just wanted to pass the key. Now the problem is solved. I am no longer getting that warning.

Answer (score 3):

I believe your code is incorrect on this line:

```
{f[key].map((val) => {
```

you already retrieved the keys for `f` here:

```
 const key = Object.keys(f);
```

So what your code should actually look like is:

```
const filterList = filterBy.map((f, i) => {
    const keys = Object.keys(f);
    return (
      <div key={i} className="filter">
        <h4 className="filter__header">{keys}</h4>
        {keys.map((val) => {
          return (
            <CheckBoxInput
              key={val} // then just use the f property key as the key (if unique)
              changeVal={(e) => changeValHandler(e, key)}
              value={val.toLowerCase()}
              label={val}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  });
```

Then just use the f property key as the key (if unique) for the second loop of components.

---

Also not sure what you would like to display on this line

```
<h4 className="filter__header">{keys}</h4>
```

But as the code is written so far, this would display an array of keys.

Comment: Thank you. I am no longer getting key error. Yeah, you are right. It was a mistake. I needed to access the index 0 of that key array.

Answer (score 1):

You actually did it right. But there're two loops in your code, each loop needs to have the looped element tagged with a `key` prop. As long as the key is unique for that loop, that's fine.

```
  <CheckBoxInput key={...} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it like this:

```
 {f[key].map((val,i) => {
          return (
         <div key={i}>
            <CheckBoxInput
              changeVal={(e) => changeValHandler(e, key)}
              value={val.toLowerCase()}
              label={val}
            />
         </div>
```